# Return value from a generator object python

Tags: python

I have this code that extracts only digits from a string :

```
infotype = (int(s) for s in chooseMappingStr.split() if s.isdigit())
```

If i print infotype it returns a generator object :

```
'<generator object dBQuery_foreignTable.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000018A60CF33C0>'
```

Is there a way to return a int value from it ?

Comment: you need to use for loop on infotype again to get the values in the generator.

Comment: What you are looking at is the generator itself. You haven't actually asked the generator for any of its content. Do you know what a generator is and how to use them? Why do you use a generator if you are unsure how to use it?

Comment: To get the current value you can use `next(infotype)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `[]` instead of `()`:

```
infotype = [int(s) for s in chooseMappingStr.split() if s.isdigit()]
```